# Unable to execute jshell from Mac Terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal, java-9, jshell

I am currently using java 1.8 on my Mac Sierra.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Now I want to run "jshell" for executing simple java commands right from the terminal. But I ended up with the following error message -

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jshell" (-1)
```

What is the workaround do I need to do for avoiding this error message ?

Comment: jshell is for Java 9.

Comment: Didn't knew that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217851/unable-to-execute-jshell-from-mac-terminal#comment65774121_39217851), you need to [download and install Java-9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html) for working with [jshell](/questions/tagged/jshell).

Once you have set the environment variable to make use of the `/jdk../.../bin` directory. You can execute the command `jshell` on your command line to get going.

[image]